# .htaccess mod_rewrite with GET parameters does not redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite URLs like:

```
product_reviews.php?products_id=3
```

to

```
haendlerbewertung::_::3.html
```

In my .htacces I defined:

```
RewriteRule ^haendlerbewertung::_::([^/]*)\.html$ product_reviews.php?products_id=$1 [L]
```

This rewrite rule works as it should, but there is no redirection from old to new URL, so each site can be called with 2 different URLs. If I write [L,R=301] the new URL wil be redirected to the old, but that's wrong. The old URL should be redirected to new one. So what's wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect old url to the new one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product_reviews.php\?products_id=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /haendlerbewertung::_::%1.html? [NE,L,R]
# map new url to the old one
RewriteRule ^haendlerbewertung::_::([^/]*)\.html$ /product_reviews.php?products_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That doesn't work. 
product_reviews.php?products_id=3 
redirects to
haendlerbewertung::_::%252.html with 404 status code

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. I have updated the code with correct syntax.

Comment: Sorry, same result

Comment: Clear your browser cache and then Try the updated code.